# Install C# Application/Program in Client PC (Under one Network) remotely

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I want to install my application into client PC (1000 PCs) without going and installing it manually.

For example, TrendMicro antivirus installs Antivirus client to every client PC remotely just sitting from the Admin PC.

I want same procedure like this.

Can you please help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this, it may help: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/211

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy the software from a network share using GPO (Group Policy) linked to an organizational unit (OU) in Active Directory, per machine.

Answer (score 0):

And as **@scheien** suggest, by using Group Policy after building an MSI file. [here is a link showing you how to do it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remote-install-windows-software/)